# Wordpress Use Theme for Blog Only

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wish to use the [Pinbin](http://colorlib.com/wp/pinbin/) theme for my Wordpress blog only. I have created a custom theme for everything else, but for the blog, I would like to use this theme.

I took the main index php file from this template, along with the header and footer files. I renamed the header and footer files, and changed the header/footer calls to these files rather than the ones used by the rest of the site.

I assigned the theme to a page, but it's not showing any posts. The code is as follows:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<div id="post-area">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
<div class="pinbin-image"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'summary-image' );  ?></a></div>
<div class="pinbin-category"><p><?php the_category(', ') ?></p></div>
<?php } ?>
<div class="pinbin-copy"><h2><a class="front-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p class="pinbin-date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>  </p>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
<p class="pinbin-link"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">&rarr;</a></p>
</div>
</div>       
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any ideas on why I'm not seeing anything?

Thanks, S

Answer (score 0):

The `index.php` file is used as a backup if there's no other template defined, you'll have to edit a different file if you want to edit a certain page type. See [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview) in the WordPress codex.

  +

You forgot an `endif;` at the bottom of your file.

[image: Template hierachy WordPress]

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that simple -- this theme is using the index.php file. I put a comment there and it's in the source.